# Get active link in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am attempting to get the active link in Angular 2 so I can update my css in my template.

This is what I have done with the help of google:

```
export class AppComponent {
    router: Router;

    constructor(data: Router) {
        this.router = data;
    }

    isActive(tab): boolean {
        if (this.router.currentInstruction && this.router.currentInstruction.component.routeData) {
            return tab == this.router.currentInstruction.component.routeData.data['activeTab'];
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**My template is as follows:**

```
  <li class="some-class" [ngClass]="{active: isActive('some-route')}">

                <a [routerLink]="['SomeRoute']" class="menu-item" ><span>Link1</span></a>

            </li>
```

While this works, I note the [RouterLink directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouterLink-directive.html) has the method: isRouteActive.

This would seem like a sensible way to manipulate the link class using this.

**But how do I use it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update RC.3:**

In RC.3 there was a new directive [`routerLinkActive`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html) added.

```
routerLinkActive="classA classB class" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"
```

**Original:**

Angular router sets `router-link-active` class automatically on active router links.

If you want custom classes you can use something like

- [Changing the default name of "router-link-active" class by writing a custom directive that adds new class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36537878/changing-the-default-name-of-router-link-active-class-by-writing-a-custom-dire/36539806#36539806)
- [In Angular 2 how do I assign a custom class to an active router link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965853/in-angular-2-how-do-i-assign-a-custom-class-to-an-active-router-link)

See also

- [Angular: How to determine active route with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571517/angular-2-how-to-determine-active-route-with-parameters/35046555#35046555)
- [In Angular, how do you determine the active route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323480/in-angular-2-how-do-you-determine-the-active-route/34823981#34823981)
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5334

Comment: ok - I think I get it, so I need to simply style the class: "router-link-active".

Comment: Exactly. . . . . . . .