# Set state based on current route in Angular2 (RC3)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

Let's say I have the typical setup, a side menu where I can pick an option and an area to the right where the content for this option is displayed.

I'd like to build the side menu using a series of `routerLink` directives like so:

```
@Component({
selector: 'side-menu',
template: `
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a [routerLink]="['/option1']">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a [routerLink]="['/option2']">Option 2</a></li>
            <li><a [routerLink]="['/option3']">Option 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
`
})
```

In addition, I'd like the corresponding `<li>` to be highlighted, using `class="active"`, for example. How do I do that?

Of course, there's always `click()` plus event handler, but I figure using just `routerLink` here is much cleaner than handling events.

I'd like to provide a plnkr, but it seems the current Angular2 template is broken once you import from `@angular/router`, I guess that is because of the router bundle missing from RC3 in the npm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like the corresponding `<li>` to be highlighted, using `class="active"`, for example. How do I do that?

As we know angular2's router chnages continuesly so ASAIK with new router of angular2 this is very easy using
`routerLinkActive` directive in your `routerLink` . for example

```
<a [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['/Demo']">
    Hello Link
</a>
```

here is working plunker <kbd>[Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/eqdqSI?p=preview)</kbd>

also there are many similer question are there

- [Angular 2: How to determine active route with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34571517/5043867)
- [In Angular 2 how do you determine the active route?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34323480/5043867)
- [In Angular 2 how do I assign a custom class to an active router link?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34965853/5043867)

## Update

sometimes it throw error

> Cannot read property 'pathsWithParams' of undefined
>   so you have to define this as well with routerLinkActive

```
[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
```

see here

- [Angular2(RC-4) :Cannot read property 'pathsWithParams' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38673804/5043867)

Comment: can you subscribe to the current path though, to help with creating a breadcrumb?

Comment: Sorry I don't know