# Angular2(RC-4) :Cannot read property 'pathsWithParams' of undefined

Tags: angular, routes

while using child routing in angular2 RC-4 getting this error

> Cannot read property 'pathsWithParams' of undefined

my routing file contains

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'demo', component: DummyComponent },
  { path: 'user-profile', component: UserProfileComponent,
    children:[
      { path: '', component: ProfileOverview },
      { path: 'smart-points', component: ProfileSmartPoints }
    ]},
]
```

any idea ?

## update

The problem is actully whenever i use `routerLinkActive` in the html side

Comment: Do you have any code refer to that `pathsWithParams` property?

Comment: nop i have no parameter in my routing

Comment: If you reproduce it with plunker, I'm sure you would be able to solve it on your own while doing that.

Comment: yup sort out where exactly the problem is : the problem is whenever i have used `routerLinkActive`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer thanks @micronyks

actually the probelm is we have to use the property `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"` while using 
`routerLinkActive="active-link"` in the html for checking active route.

so the correct syntax for this is :

```
<a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" [routerLink]='["./Dummy"]'>Dummy</a>
```

Comment: I knew it because it is not a general error. it was `something missing` error  which is hard to find. But great to know that you got it.

Comment: Yups thanks :) posted as answer may be it is beneficial for someone else