# In Angular 2 how do you determine the active route in Child Routing with parent routing?

Tags: angular, routes

Facing problem while child routing in angular2 that how to highlight the active route. i know for parent routing we can use

```
routerLinkActive="active"
```

but in case of child routing i have to highlight parent as well as child route both. how to do this ?

referring from here

- [In Angular 2 how do you determine the active route?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34323480/5043867)

Answer (score 6):

In fact you don't have to use `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"` anywhere. Just use `routerLinkActive="active"`. This way you will be able to see parent and its child route active at a same time.

For further reference : https://plnkr.co/edit/UoojNRslgeqfkF83Qgym?p=preview - check **contact route**.

Comment: yes i know but if i am not using `...exact:true...` than some problems occur see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/38673498/5043867

Comment: I can only help you with your plunker. I feel like you must have missed something somewhere. You can check my plunker its working as expected with RC.4.

Comment: yes you are right but i am unable to produce the same problem on plunker right now :( is there any other option there for the same  ?

Comment: I'm not sure but lookin at your other question, I feel like you have some problem with `routerLink`. I'm not sure though. You can check and compare with my plunker and hopefully it will work.