# disable/hide directive based on route Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have routes defined in my app.component.ts file as follows

```
@View({
    templateUrl: 'assets/home.html',
    directives: [AccountManagerComponent, HeaderComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],

})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: '/about', name: 'About', component: AboutComponent },    
    { path: '/', name: 'IdentityManager', component: IdentityManagerComponent, useAsDefault: true}    
])
```

template in home.html is as follow.

```
<header id="ag-header" class="app-header" role="banner"></header>
<section id="ag-content" class="page-login">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
```

now i want to disable/hide 'header' element if i am at identitycomponent.

So can i view/hide directives in template based on the route?

Answer (score 0):

```
<header *ngIf="isIdentityManager" id="ag-header" class="app-header" role="banner"></header>
<section id="ag-content" class="page-login">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
```

```
constructor( router: Router) {
  router.subscribe(value => {
    this.isIdentityManager = router.currentInstruction.component.routeName == 'IdentityManager';
  });
}
```

See also [In Angular 2 how do you determine the active route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323480/in-angular-2-how-do-you-determine-the-active-route)

Comment: i have added 

import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, Router} from 'angular2/router';

But got error that router.currentInstruction is not a function

Comment: Is the code (routes) and HTML in your question from the same component?

Comment: Can you try to update this Plunker to allow to reproduce? https://plnkr.co/edit/yckJKY?p=preview