# Hide elements based on routing in Angular2 rc1

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have some elements I want on every page except the login page. I'd like to use ngIf or possibly the hidden property of the elements to hide those elements when the user is on the login page.

I have tried this:

```
<div [hidden]="router.isRouteActive(router.generate('/login'))">
```

based on this question and answer: [In Angular 2 how do you determine the active route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323480/in-angular-2-how-do-you-determine-the-active-route)

And have also tried this:

```
 <div *ngIf="!router.isRouteActive(router.generate('/login'))">
```

but haven't had any success.

For reference here is the component that matches this html.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from 'node_modules/@angular/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, XHRBackend } from 'node_modules/@angular/http';
import { Routes, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from 'node_modules/@angular/router';

import { LoginService } from './login/login.service';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'portal',
    templateUrl: 'portal/portal.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, LoginComponent, UserComponent ],
    providers: [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        LoginService
    ]
})

@Routes([
    { path: '/login', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: '/user/:username', component: UserComponent}
])

export class PortalComponent implements OnInit{
    private router: Router
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']); 
    } 
}
```

The documentation for isRouteActive is pretty slim, the same for generate. Any direction on a better way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to find the syntax I needed for rc1 buried in a comment here: [In Angular 2 how do you determine the active route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323480/in-angular-2-how-do-you-determine-the-active-route)

```
<div *ngIf="!router.urlTree.contains(router.createUrlTree(['/login']))">
```

Comment: Yes! Finally, I found the answer I've been looking for. Thank you.

Comment: `contains` is not native javascript. For people trying to search for a string in the url see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41684866/4194436

Answer (score 46):

Simply check the `router.url` in the template:

`my.component.ts`

```js
...
constructor(public router: Router){}
...
```

`my.component.html`

```html
<div *ngIf="router.url != '/login'">
    <h2>Not in login!</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect Answer :)

Comment: This solution might break if you have auxiliary routes.

Answer (score 20):

This is what I did for Angular2 RC5 router :

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

public location = '' ;

constructor(private  _router : Router) 
{      
  this.location = _router.url;
}
```

In HTML :

```
<div *ngIf = "location == '/home' ">
</div>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: even you can use _router.url on the HTML. This way will refreshing the router as it changes

Answer (score 9):

You can hide/show elements by checking the url for specific component,

Modify your **component.ts** file like this,

```
import { RouterModule, Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

hideElement = false;

constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      if (event.url === '/login') {
        this.hideElement = true;
      }  else {
        this.hideElement = false;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Use this `hideElement` property in **component.html**

```
<div [hidden]="hideElement">
```

Answer (score 7):

I had to do something similar in my code.  I did this programmatically by creating the list of routes I wanted to exclude my element from showing in.

In my class, I injected the `Location` object from `@angular/common`.

```
public isHidden() {
  let list = ["/login"],
      route = this.location.path();

  return (list.indexOf(route) > -1);
}
```

Then in my template, I use the `hidden` attribute and bind it to my function.

`<div id="elementToHide" [hidden]="isHidden()"></div>`

Answer (score 7):

All of the solutions did not work out as expected. If you have route with parameters. You can use ES6 `includes`:

```
<div *ngIf="!_router.url.includes('login')">Show me except on login page</div>
```

Comment: But this does not work on Refresh as the module does not load again in my case.

Answer (score 5):

There is a hack we can use in some simple cases. It is based on `RouterLinkActive` directive that can be added not only to anchors but to it's parents also. So we can do the following:

```
<div routerLinkActive="hidden">
    <a routerLink="/login">Login</a>
</div>
```

`hidden` is a standard bootstrap class:

```
.hidden {
    display: none!important;
}
```

How it works: when you are inside login area, the `hidden` class is added and you do not see the `div`. Once you navigate to another route, the `hidden` class disappears and the div is visible.

The drawback is that you require to have a link with `routerLink` inside the `div`.

Answer (score 2):

RxJS example (Observable):

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent{
    hideElement$: Observable<boolean> = this.router.events
        .pipe(
            filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
            map((data: any) => data.url === '/login')
        );
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="!(hideElement$ | async)">
  <p>Hide me on Login page!</p>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based off of @Michelangelo's  Comment:

In Your Component:

```
import { Routes, Router } from 'node_modules/@angular/router';

export class YourComponent implements OnInit{
     constructor(public router: Router ) {
    }
}
```

In HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!router.url.includes('admin')">
    <p>The content you want to hide when in the above url path</p>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

At least with more recent versions of angular 2 and depending on the specific use case.You can transclude the content and only add it on the route component where you want it. Much better than maintaining a list of routes and using ngIf conditions.

In your component template.
Add an ngcontent element and use select to give it a name

```
<ng-content select="[content-name]"></ng-content>
```

Then you can use that component and transclude the content.

```
<component>
<div content-name> transcluded content</div>
</component>
```

Or use it without referencing the transcluded content

```
<component>
</component>
```

Answer (score -3):

I would try `router.generate(['/login'])` rather than `router.generate('/login')`.

This syntax sometimes is tricky.

I hope this helps in your case

Comment: You're correct on the syntax, but this still didn't resolve my issue. I was able to find the right syntax in a comment on a different question.