# Hide Header Component on certain route (Angular 5)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a header that I want to hide on certain routes

When your on the home there is nothing next to the route so `www.mywebsite.com` but then when you log in the route will always have `app` in it so every page from now on will look like this `www.mywebsite.com/app/whatever`basically I want to hide my header when the route has `app` in it

I have tried to do this.. but It doesnt seem to be working

Any help would be appreciated and if you know a better way to do this please let me know!

**component.html**

```
<home-header *ngIf="router != '/app'"></home-header>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


export class RootComponent {
     router: string;

     constructor(
        private _router: Router
     ) {
         this.router = _router.url;
     }
}
```

**EDIT**

I have tried to do this..

```
<home-header *ngIf="router.indexOf('app') > -1"></home-header>
```

and that did not work

I have also tried to do this..

```
 export class RootComponent {
    router: string;

    constructor(
        private _router: Router
    ) {
        this._router.events.subscribe(() => this.router = this._router.url );
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to find a solution from http://stackoverflow.com/a/41684866/4194436

In your **component.ts**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

//...

constructor(
   public router: Router
)
```

then in your **component.html**

```
<home-header *ngIf="!router.url.includes('app')"></home-header>
```

So basically if the route url does not include 'app' show the `home-header` component.

So basically if the route doesn't include `app` show the `home-header`

Comment: It does not work on IE because includes is not supported.
And with indexOf solution I got "Expected the operants to be of similar type or any" error in VS code

Comment: You can use a polyfill https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221341/ie-does-not-support-includes-method

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the router variable only one time, you should add a subscription to the variable changes :

```
constructor(private _router: Router) {
   // this.router = _router.url;
   this._router.events.subscribe(()=> this.router = this._router.url );
}
```

You can find more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548895/8945135).

Don't forget to unsubscribe on component destruction to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Can you please make a stackblitz for your issue ?

Comment: I was able to find the answer, `<home-header *ngIf="!_router.url.includes('app')"></home-header>`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
*ngIf="router.indexOf('app') > -1"
```

Hope this helps