# Angular 2.0.0-rc3: partial route matching with routerLinkActive

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I'm using `routerLinkActive` in my primary routing.

```
<a [routerLink]="/user" routerLinkActive="active">Bob</a>
```

When the URL is `/user`, the `active` class will be added to the `a` tag, but under the primary route, I also have a few secondary routes, so 
when the URL is `/user/aa`, the active will be removed.

I hope that when the URL is either `/user/aa` or `/user/bb`, the primary route's class `active` still exists.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: false }"
```

As far as I know this is going to be the default with the next update.

Comment: add it to the primary routing?<a [routerLink]="/user" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: false }">Bob</a>

Comment: Where you have the `routerLinkActive` attribute.