# Show div when router is not equal - angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to show this code only, if router is not equal '' and '/dashboard'.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a routerLink="/dashboard"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a service and set a flag when user navigate to ***/dashboard.*** 
Get the flag injecting the service and use as a condition with the `*ngIf`

### Edit

> Please take a look to the official documentation for [RouterLinkActive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html%20directive) directive.

In your case you can define a simple css class

```
.hidden {
    visibility:hidden;
 }
```

and apply it when the routerLinkActive is /dashboard

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" 
     routerLinkActive="hidden" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a routerLink="/dashboard"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check following URL, Here is define exact solutions which you want.
[In Angular 2 how do you determine the active route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323480/in-angular-2-how-do-you-determine-the-active-route)

1. First you need to bind the property.

   Your Tab Name
2. On basis of property you need to call a function (YourFunction) and pass your route.
3. Inside TS file you can check that your router is Active or Not, and then set a flag.
4. Use that flag with NgIf in to you your div which you want to show/hide.