# Angular2 add class when route is inactive

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Angular2 has a **routerLinkActive** directive which adds class to the element if the route is active. I want to add a class when route is **inactive**. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "inactive" in this case? There can only be on active route at one point in time, and the rest would be "inactive"?.... or are you looking for a way to disable a route?

Comment: You could do this with CSS. Set the routerlinkactive to `active` and then do `a:not(.active)`.

Comment: Yes, by "active" I mean current route.
Unfortunately in my case other library uses the class and I can't override it using css.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<a routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" [ngClass]="rla.isActive ? 'classIfActive' : 'classIfNotActive'">
</a>
```