# routerLink negation condition

Tags: angular2-routing, routerlink

im trying to add "not" conditional to routerlink using Angular 2. My use case is that i want the pages to have a default class everytime im not in the home page, and i dont want to add the class for every page. It is for showging a sidebar, that only is hidden on home page. So:

```
[routerLink]="/home" routerLinkActive="fit sidebar"
```

That is what i would like to negate. Like this:

```
[routerLink]!="/home" routerLinkActive="fit sidebar"
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the difference in terms of classes between the 2 assignments?

Comment: One has a "!" negating the condition

Comment: do you want to add this class to the `routerLinkActive` attribute or on a different part of the page? Could you please specify where you wanna add this 'class' to exactly?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41982420/717732