# A route is not active if the url matches but contains query params

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular-routing, query-string

I'm having hard times at understanding if a route is active or not, regardless of optional URL parameters (that can be `query parameters`, `hash` and so on).

When I set `{exact: true}` as `routerLinkActiveOptions` and I go to */login*, then `[routerLinkActive]` or `router.isActive('/login')` will return `true` as expected.

But if I add some query param to the url, like `/login?err=something_happened`, then they will return `false`, but I expect it to returns `true` as well.

Therefore, if there are query params in the URL then none of the items in the navbar will have applied the specified classes, and this is just not what a user expects.

I could also write that method by myself but I prefer an Angular solution, particularly because there are many standards for URL parameters so it wouldn't be easy to implement.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323480) didn't help me, though it provides many solutions.

Do you know a way to accomplish it?

Comment: Would it be possible to store the desired data in a service instead of passing it on the URL to avoid this problem?

Comment: Yes, there could be many workarounds, but the easier way was putting the error message in the URL (if it worked...) so I may show the message redirecting from both client or server

Comment: There is an open issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6459) but a year later it hasn't still been fixed