# Setting <li> class to active with angular 4 based on router

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am pretty new with angular 4 and i have this problem that i cant solve on my own.

My home url is **localhost:4200/**, and the other one is **localhost:4200/wortschaz**.

I want to use angular *ngIf to give an active class to a certain div based on router. So if url is **localhost:4200/wortschaz** then i want to set class to a div that has content for that.

Can somebody help me with this one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Angular 2 how do you determine the active route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323480/in-angular-2-how-do-you-determine-the-active-route)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *routerLinkActive*

```html
<a  routerLink="/wortschaz" routerLinkActive="activeNav">Wortschaz</a>
```

```css
.activeNav {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `<li><a routerLink='/wortschaz ' routerLinkActive='active'>wortschaz </a></li>`. The `routerLinkActive` takes care of it