# How do you record and intercept routing calls in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I need to record and intercept routing calls in the app, because the app contains multiple tabs and I want to facilitate a history function between the tabs and upper tabs (higher level tabs).

Recording would be required for the browsing history as I've mentioned and interception for some future usage. I hope this is possible with Angular in the first place..

I found this [In Angular, how do you determine the active route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323480/in-angular-how-do-you-determine-the-active-route) but I'm not sure how can I implement it for my use case.

**UPDATE**

To clarify, my app has three main tabs in one of which there are 5 subtabs. The functionality I want to have is that when I click in any order and way I am able to navigate back and forth using the browser back and forward buttons.

Comment: Have you considered `Router.events`?

Comment: @AndreiGătej thanks for the tip, no, I did not, because I was not aware of this functionality. Not quite sure how to implement it for my use case though :/

Comment: Could you add an example to your question?